# Как выводить беззнаковые (unsigned) числа в printf?

Tags: c, c++

Есть код:

```
unsigned long x = 0;

printf("x = %d\n");
```

Компилятор показывает предупреждение:

> `example.cc:139:35: предупреждение: format «%d» expects argument of type «int», but argument 2 has type «long unsigned int» [-Wformat]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужен спецификатор `%lu`.

[printf - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)